# Knock knock, who's there?

Tags: riddle

> There is someone knocking at the door, she is very famous, has a
>   television show and is married to a girl with a name which sounds
>   similar to Porsche. She loves Porsches and that's why she married one.

So who is knocking on the door?

Comment: She doesn't have a televission show anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be

> Ellen DeGeneres. She has her own television show and her wife's name is Portia, which sounds like Porche.

Comment: Ellen DeGeneres doesn't have a television show.